# IBM MQ with JMS and .Net

Tags: c#, jms, ibm-mq

Are the WCF / .Net demos provided with IBM MQ still applicable if you use JMS with IBM MQ? Or do I need to write directly to JMS from .Net? (Very ignorant here if you couldn't tell).  If I have to write to JMS directly then I guess i could use JNBridge or something.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they still apply.  You'll find that you have much better performance using a direct DLL for the server instead of a bridge, since the DLL directly implements the underlying messaging protocol for the server.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAment.  Do you have any specific documentation I could reference about what you explain above (or examples).  Thanks for the info!

Comment: This redbook may give you more info specific to MQ Series: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247012.html